# How to pass webdriverio driver into functions for modular design?

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io

I am using webdriverio for communicating with appium server. I am trying to automate Instagram interactions. Each automation needs me to login, and logout. So, I am thinking of writing a function that logs in and a function that logs out.

Currently, I've something that looks like this:

```
const wdio = require("webdriverio");
const opts = {...}
const client = wdio.remote(opts)

const login = (client, username, password) => {
  return client
    .click("#log_in_button")
    .click("#login_username")
    .keys(username)
    .click("#password")
    .keys(password)
    .click("#button_text");
}

const someOtherAction = (client) => {
  // More actions performed on client
  // ...
}

client.init();
login(client, "username", "password")
  .someOtherAction(client);
```

This doesn't work ^^, however same code when written this way works:

```
client
  .init()
  .click("#log_in_button")
  .click("#login_username")
  .keys("username")
  .click("#password")
  .keys("password")
  .click("#button_text")
  .waitForExist("~Activity") // Some other actions...
```

I suspect this has to do with `this` not being correctly set, I have tried looking at the source of webdriverio, but I didn't quite understand it. So, how could I pass around the driver so that I can write more modular, usable and maintainable code?

Also, I don't quite understand how this chaining of commands is working, since the api docs at http://webdriver.io doesn't state anything about the return value of function calls like `click`, `keys`, etc. but yet, they seem to work as if they are returning the `client` itself. If someone could explain the chaining as well, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I achieved the modularity by making login a `async` function and `await`ing for the action to occur.

```
const login = async (client, username, password) => {
  await client
   .click("#log_in_button")
   .click("#login_username")
   .keys(username)
   .click("#password")
   .keys(password)
   .click("#button_text");
}
```

And then using it as:

```
const client = wdio.remote(opts);
(async() => {
  await client.init();
  await login(client, 'username', 'password');
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to write tests with WebdriverIO is via PageObject pattern. There is an [example](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/examples/pageobject) directory in the GitHub repo. It is also a good idea to check out the [boilerplate section](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/boilerplate.html) where people from the WebdriverIO community provided useful starter packs to get going quickly.